# Combining Strategies (Design Patterns)

Tags: design, strategy

If I have two boolean variables B1 and B2 whose value combinations cover four independent behavior functions (MFF, MFT, MTF, MTT), then how many concrete strategy (design pattern) classes should I create?
From the single responsibility rule, it seems like I'd need a strategy interface with a single method, and four concrete strategy classes.
Because if I had just two concrete strategy classes (one for B1 true and another for B1 being false), then the strategy method would be conditional on B2, right?
I ask this because it seems like this solution does not scale well; I suppose if another boolean B3 was introduced, I'd need eight strategy classes, and so on.
Am I on the right track; is strategy the right pattern here?
Sorry, I cannot be more specific. The more general question is 'How should the GOF Strategy Pattern be implemented against two or more variables to have independent behavior for each combination.' Thanks for the comments; they are sufficient.

Comment: It is hard to answer this, because it might be the case that B1 and B2 are not needed. I would stay away from boolean flags as parameters, because of the combinational explosion. What is the case you have that would need to be covered? It might be, that you would only need to create 2 strategies for what each flag means and then combine them into some sort of a pipeline.

Comment: The question is pretty abstract.  Can you articulate motivation for separate classes?  I might consider lighter weight things first: ranging from a single parameterized method to multiple instances of a single class (i.e. parameterized in construction), before adopting multiple classes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't buy  "I cannot be more specific." - that's an excuse for "I am too lazy to invest an hour to bring my actual problem into a form which describes the real problem without disclosing confidentials". One does not decide about pattern usage just by the abstract "structure" of a problem - one needs real world context, and if you are not going to present some context, don't expect anyone here to give you a useful answer.

Comment: ... from what you currently wrote, one cannot even say if the strategy pattern is really the right tool for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before letting Combinational Explosion force you to create 4 concrete classes take a good look at the decorator pattern. Sometimes you can tease the behavior differences apart and combine them at the construction level rather then at the concrete level.